# dim_lookup syntax

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to understand the syntax of a dim_lookup

```
dim_lookup('1',2,'3')
```

1 - table name from where you will fetch your data
2 - table attribute you will need to fetch your data, its like the WHERE of an sql statement
3 - the data that will be fetched based on your table attribute (2)

i.e. dim_lookup('students',student_id,'name') is equal to

```
SELECT name
FROM students
WHERE student_id
```

Can it contain a condition?

```
dim_lookup('students',student_id,'name')='12345'
```

or should it be

```
dim_lookup('students',student_id,'name')  
...  
WHERE student_id='12345'
```

Comment: hi, this is related to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869837/sql-hive-subquery-error.  Looks like dim_lookup is a user defined function so you need to look at the code to understand it or ask around in your team/group who created it. Assuming that dim_lookup returns a name based on the student_id then dim_lookup('students',student_id,'name')='12345' will return a boolean (true or false).  Meanwhile, dim_lookup('students',student_id,'name')='12345' where student_id will return the student name for student_id 12345. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really related but is part of the code; really just want to understand. You are correct on that, user-defined function.

Comment: thanks. So depending on your desired result; the first one will give you a list of all students and either say "this student is not student=12345" or "this is student=12345" (boolean type: either true or false) while the 2nd one will give you "this is student=12345" (only one row)